# Quantum Graph state paper query (Phy Rev A)

Tags: graph-states

The authors of the paper Graph States for Quantum Secret Sharing https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.78.042309 define a 'labeled state' as
$$|G_{\vec{l}}\rangle=\bigotimes_{i}X_i^{l_{i1}}Z_i^{l_{i2}}|G\rangle$$where G is a graph state.
Then they define an 'encoded graph state' as $$ |G_{\vec{l}_{*2}}\rangle=\bigotimes_{i}Z_i^{l_{i2}}|G\rangle $$ and say that the encoded graph state is the labeled graph state with $l_{1i}=0, \forall i$.

Here $\vec{l}_{i*}=(l_{i1},l_{i2})$ for the i-th vertex, $\vec{l}_{*j}=(l_{1j},l_{2j},....l_{nj})$ for the $j$ th bit over all the $n$ vertices, and $\vec{l}=(\vec{l}_{1*}, \vec{l}_{2*},........\vec{l}_{n*}$, each $l_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$.

With this framework they try to define a secret sharing protocol. However before the actual protocol, they give an example. I am understanding bits of the theory but not all of it, Here it is

1. For a 4-party scheme, they prepare a graph state $$Z^{l_{12}}\otimes Z^{l_{22}}\otimes Z^{l_{32}}\otimes Z^{l_{42}} \left(|0+++\rangle+|1---\rangle\right)$$, corresponding to this they have 4 stabilizers (generators) of the stabilizer group $K_1=XZZZ,K_2=ZXII,K_3=ZIXI,K_4=ZIIX$, with eigenvalues $(l_{12},l_{22},l_{32},l_{42})$.

My first understanding about the eigenvalues is that $l_{i2}$ are eigenvalues because those are the indices (powers) where we have possible commuting issues between the $X$ and $Z$ gate, so when they are zero the eigenvalues are $1$ and when they are $1$ they eigenvalues are $-1$, and correspondingly the the graph states are orthogonal (since they correspond to different eigenvalues). Is my undertanding okay or atleast near okay? Shouldn't the eigenvalues be
$(-1)^{l_{i2}} \forall~i$?

Comment: The authors of *what*??

Comment: I have just added that Sir

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: You need to ask just one question per post. That's why there was a close vote.

Comment: Okay I though since it was sought of continuous i asked them.